# How to make a multi step header

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a header of multistage form containing the page number and description .

What I want to do is divide each step with an arrow mark something like this

```
1 step > 2tep > 3 step> 4 step
```

This is mostly a css question I just need to know  how to make those boder into arrow sign

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vicky_Anand/ZzCA2/33/)

**Explanation**

As you can see in the fiddle I have icons that changes to check mark when you slide to next step . So I am trying to separate these icons with `>` arrow and then add some css `background` colors to separate the `active`,`previous`, `next` steps

Comment: why cant you use the > char?

Comment: So problem is not related to js, and you don't know how to write `&gt;` ?

Comment: @Justinas updated the fiddle have a look

Comment: @SandeepRajoria yes I am trying to do something with that

Comment: Have a look at this: http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-breadcrumb-navigation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your fiddle, does this do what you want?

```
.divider:before { content: ">"; }
```

Comment: I am trying it but I think I have to play around with the css little more

Answer (score 0):

are you searching something like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6R38/) (I've done a simple arrow with text)?

```
.generatecssdotcom_arrowpoint {position:absolute;top:0;right:0;font-size:8px;color:#cccccc;}
.generatecssdotcom_arrowpoint a {color:#cccccc;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal;}
.generatecssdotcom_arrowpoint a:hover {color:#cccccc;text-decoration:none;font-weight:normal;}
.generatecssdotcom_arrow {text-align:left;font-size:24px;font-family:Georgia;color:#000000;width:250px;height:30px;position:relative;background:#E46B00;border:7px solid #FFCC00;margin:7px 41px 7px 7px;padding:10px;}
.generatecssdotcom_arrow:after, .generatecssdotcom_arrow:before {left:100%;top:50%;border:solid transparent;content:" ";height:0;width:0;position:absolute;pointer-events:none;}
.generatecssdotcom_arrow:after {border-left-color:#E46B00;border-width:34px;margin-top:-34px;}
.generatecssdotcom_arrow:before {border-left-color:#FFCC00;border-width:44px;margin-top:-44px;}
```

refer this [site](http://www.generatecss.com/advanced/arrow/) to generate it

for a single arrow refer this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yG4GS/1/)

```
.arrow-right {
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid green;
}



 <div class="arrow-right"></div>
```

Comment: no  as you can see in my Fiddle the buttons I want to divide with an arrow marks and then add some css to give back ground color to differentiate between active previous and next steps

Comment: update my answer, hope it help to build your elements